# Making PySNMP resolve Object IDs

Tags: python, networking, snmp, pysnmp

I'm trying to do a SNMP-walk with PySNMP. I wrote the following script, which works, but for every device I "walk" the OIDs of only about ten rows can be resolved to a "real name".

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from os.path import exists
import sys
import os

# Turn on debugging
#debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('msgproc', 'secmod'))

# Enter parameters
target_IP           = raw_input('Target IP (192.168.13.100): ') or '192.168.13.100'
target_port         = raw_input('Target port (161): ') or 161
max_timeout         = int(raw_input('Maximum timeout in seconds (1):')) or 1
max_retries         = int(raw_input('Maximum number of retries (0):')) or 0
target_file_name    = raw_input('Target filename (.txt is added): ') + '.txt' 

# Check for already existing file
path = 'walks/'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
if exists(path+target_file_name):
    sys.exit("The file '%s' already exists. Try again." % target_file_name)
else: 
    target_file = open(path+target_file_name, 'w+')

# Initialize counter to zero
counter = 0

# Create command generator
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

# Get data

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((target_IP, target_port), timeout=max_timeout, retries=max_retries),
    '1.3', 
    lexicographicMode=True, 
    #maxRows=1000, 
    ignoreNonIncreasingOid=True,
    lookupNames=True
)

# Print errors and values to file
if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    # Print error messages

    if errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
            )
        )
    else:
        # Print values
        for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
            for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                counter += 1
                target_file.write("(%s)\t %s value = \t%s\n" % (counter, name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))

        # Finish the operation                
        target_file.close()
        print('Writing to %s successful. %d lines have been written' % (target_file_name, counter))
        sys.exit(0)
```

The result is a file with very many rows.
the first entrys look like this:

```
(1)  SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr."0" value =   Hirschmann MAR
(2)  SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID."0" value =    1.5.6.9.1.1.248.4.10.90
(3)  SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime."0" value =  2626357
(4)  SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact."0" value =     Hirschmann Automation and Control GmbH
(5)  SNMPv2-MIB::sysName."0" value =    mar1030.plc-s7-15000
(6)  SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation."0" value =    Hirschmann MAR
(7)  SNMPv2-MIB::sysServices."0" value =    2
(8)  SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange."0" value =    300
```

But then the OIDs are not resolved anymore:

```
(9)  SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2."2.1.0" value =  27
(10)     SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2."2.2.1.1.1" value =  1
(11)     SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2."2.2.1.1.2" value =  2
(12)     SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2."2.2.1.1.3" value =  3
.....
```

What causes this and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve MIBs with pysnmp you have to load them into pysnmp engine prior to make SNMP queries. Your script performs MIB resolution for SNMPv2-MIB because it is automatically loaded by pysnmp engine.

To make use of plain-text MIBs with pysnmp you have to convert them from plain text form (e.g. ASN.1) into pysnmp format (Python code). You could use the build-pysnmp-mib shell script (based on libsmi) or download and install a pre-compiled pack of common MIBs (pysnmp-mibs Python package).

To load some or all available MIBs you could use the MibVariable.loadMibs(*mibs) method. See [this script](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v3-pull-whole-mib-with-options.html) for example.

Comment: Okay, i already installed the MIB-pack. Now when I just use `cmdgen.MibVariable('IF-MIB', '').loadMibs()` as argument I get an even larger file, but - as I understand - only of the "IF-branch". So if I enter `INTERNET-MIB` it should walk the whole tree from the top downwards, which might take some time. Do I understand this correctly?